# MongoDB _id as a String (MEAN Stack)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

**TL;DR** - I am trying to use a collected value from a form input as a document `_id` but am getting a 404.

I've got a modal that opens and collects form data. My first input in the form is:

`<input type="text" id="name" name="name" data-ng-model="name" />`

When I try to modify the Mongo (Mongoose) model, to use `name` as the `_id`, the form wont post. I get a 404 from `http://sitegoeshere/#!/somethings/whatever_i_type_in_for_name`

Example model:

```
var SomethingSchema = new Schema({
   _id: {
       type: String,
       default: 'default',
       trim: true
   }
}

mongoose.model('Something', SomethingSchema);
```

And in my Angular controller:

```
$scope.create = function() {

    // Create new Something object
    var something = new Somethings ({
        _id: this.name
    });

    // Redirect after save
    something.$save(function(response) {
        $location.path('somethings/' + response._id);
    }, function(errorResponse) {
        $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
    });
};
```

I've been told that MongoDB allows Strings as the _id type so what gives? Any ideas?

**UPDATE:** Here's something strange, too. I wanted to see if maybe this was a limitation or bug of Mongoose so I got into the database and created two documents:

```
> db.subnets.find().pretty()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("546bef63395b0694d51b5cbe"), "description" : "description!" }
{ "_id" : "mystring", "description" : "more description!" }
```

When I go to my app and try to pull their individual views up, I can see the data for my custom `_id` document but get a 500 Internal Server Error when I try to access the other.

```
GET http://localhost:3000/somethings/546bef63395b0694d51b5cbe 500 (Internal Server Error)
GET http://localhost:3000/somethings/mystring 200 OK
```

Comment: `somethings/` or `something/` ?, seems your collection name is `something`.

Comment: The collection is Somethings - plural. This is not a problem with the naming convention, however. If I get rid of the code that tries to use my form value for _id, I can submit the rest of the form just fine. The data saves to the correct collection and _id is simply populated with an ObjectId as normal.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely with `this.name` - looks like it's undefined.

Comment: It's not undefined. I can add a `console.log(this.name);` right before the creation of that object and it's value is logged.

Comment: Have you been calling console log _inside_ or _outside_ function? In your code `this` points to `$scope.create` function itself.

Comment: If `this.name` has a value inside of `$scope.create` and the `$Save` occurs inside `$scope.create` as well, shouldn't it be there when we attempt to create the document? (To answer your question, I can `console.log` inside `$scope.create` and get a value)

Comment: Well, it should. Can you put the code on Plunker/JsFiddle? Would be easier to find out what's the issue.